# The images uploaded into the dropzone (dropzone.js) are cropped using cropper.js, but not cropped image is displayed when publishing

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js, cropperjs

I have a code that is responsible for opening an image loaded in a drag and drop field (dropzone.js) in a modal window for cropping using cropper.js. The code is working. The modal window opens, the image is cropped and the cropped image is displayed in the drag and drop field. But after the publication the image is not cropped in a post. That is, it turns out that an uncroped image is uploaded to the server. How can this problem be solved? Here is the code.

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
var myDropzone = new Dropzone('div#myDropzone', {
url: "/plugins/dropzone/dist/upload.php",
createImageThumbnails: true,
autoProcessQueue: false,
init: function() {
   this.on("addedfile", function() {
      if (this.files[1]!=null){
      this.removeFile(this.files[0]);}
      });
   },
});

var cropped = false;
myDropzone.on('addedfile', function(file) {
    if (!cropped) {
      myDropzone.removeFile(file);
      cropper(file);
    } else {
      cropped = false;
      var previewURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      var dzPreview = $(file.previewElement).find('img');
      dzPreview.attr("src", previewURL);
    }
});

function cropper(file) {
var c = 0;
var fileName = file.name;
var loadedFilePath = getSrcImageFromBlob(file);

  var modalTemplate =
      '<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static">' +
      '<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">' +
      '<div class="modal-content">' +
      '<div class="modal-header">' +
      '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="modal-body">' +
      '<div class="cropper-container">' +
      '<img id="img-' + c + '" src="' + loadedFilePath + '" data-vertical-flip="false" data-horizontal-flip="false">' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="modal-footer">' +
      '<button type="button" class="btns btn-warning rotate-left"><i class="fa fa-rotate-left"></i></button>' +
      '<button type="button" class="btns btn-warning rotate-right"><i class="fa fa-rotate-right"></i></button>' +
      '<button type="button" class="btns btn-warning zoom-in" data-method="zoom" data-option="0.1"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></button>' +
      '<button type="button" class="btns btn-warning zoom-out" data-method="zoom" data-option="-0.1"><i class="fa fa-search-minus"></i></button>' +
      '<button type="button" class="btns btn-warning reset"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></button>' +
      '<button type="button" class="btns btn-primary crop-upload">Crop and Upload</button>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>';

    // @formatter:on

    var $cropperModal = $(modalTemplate);
    var $image = null;

    $cropperModal.modal('show').on("shown.bs.modal", function() {
      $image = $('#img-' + c);
      console.log($image);
      var cropper = $image.cropper({
          autoCropArea: 1,
          aspectRatio: 16 / 12,
          cropBoxResizable: false,
          movable: true,
          rotatable: true,
          zoomable: true,
          toggleDragModeOnDblclick: false,
          viewMode: 2
        });

      $cropperModal.on('click', '.crop-upload', function() {
          // get cropped image data
          $image.cropper('getCroppedCanvas', {
            width: 400,
            height: 300,
            minWidth: 400,
            minHeight: 300,
            maxWidth: 4096,
            maxHeight: 3072,
            fillColor: '#fff',
            imageSmoothingEnabled: false,
            imageSmoothingQuality: 'high'
          })
            .toBlob(function(blob) {
            var croppedFile = blobToFile(blob, fileName);
            croppedFile.accepted = true;
            var files = myDropzone.getAcceptedFiles();
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
              var file = files[i];
              if (file.name === fileName) {
                myDropzone.removeFile(file);
              }
            }
            cropped = true;

            myDropzone.files.push(croppedFile);
            myDropzone.emit('addedfile', croppedFile);
            myDropzone.createThumbnail(croppedFile); //, width, height, resizeMethod, fixOrientation, callback)
            $cropperModal.modal('hide');
          });
        })
        .on('click', '.rotate-right', function() {
          $image.cropper('rotate', 90);
        })
        .on('click', '.rotate-left', function() {
          $image.cropper('rotate', -90);
        })
        .on('click', '.reset', function() {
          $image.cropper('reset');
        })
        .on('click', '.zoom-in', function() {
            $image.cropper('zoom', 0.1);
        })
        .on('click', '.zoom-out', function() {
            $image.cropper('zoom', -0.1);
        })
  }).on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
    $(this).remove();
    $image.cropper('destroy');
  })
  }

  function getSrcImageFromBlob(blob) {
    var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    return urlCreator.createObjectURL(blob);
  }

  function blobToFile(theBlob, fileName) {
    theBlob.lastModifiedDate = new Date();
    theBlob.name = fileName;
    return theBlob;
  }
```

HTML code:

```
<form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php'); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="adminForm" id="adminForm" class="form-validate">
    <div class="itemAdditionalData_image">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="dropzone dz-clickable" id="myDropzone">
                <div class="dz-default dz-message" id="myAwesomeDropzone">
                    <button class="dz-button" type="button">Upload an image</button>
                </div>
                <input class="inputbox required avatar" type="file" id="image" name="image" hidden />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The code is also posted here: https://jsfiddle.net/y8m3nw1o/4/